# How to connect to a kerberos-protected cluster?

Tags: kerberos, keytab

I have a hadoop cluster that is kerberized. How do I connect to it from an external java application? I've been told I need to have a keytab and krb5 conf file but I'm not totally clear.

Comment: you need a kerberos principal (an account in the kerberos database) to be able to authenticate against kerberos using your account (the keytab is some kind of cached 
 service account credentials you use to avoid having to enter a password) first. once authenticated, you should be able to access kerberized services. and if your application relies on a system configuration, yes you will need to fill your /etc/krb5.conf with the kerberos realm information (realm name, DNS for master etc.) check kerberos tutorials online

Comment: If you are using Hadoop client libs -- make the config properties available to your `Configuration` (via `core-site.xml`etc) and set up the _static_ `UserGroupInformation` object that encapsulates JAAS and takes care of authentication. There are samples on StackOverflow

Comment: If you are using standard JDBC to access Hive or Phoenix -- define a raw JAAS config file (details depend on what the JDBC driver expects and what type of JVM you are using), there are also examples on StackOverflow

Comment: On Windows, if your Hadoop cluster uses the same Active Directory domain for Kerberos auth, you might be able to get Single Sign-On -- but that's tough. Kerberos is black magic, and Microsoft adds its own sorcery on top.